# How do I display the tomcat initialization time in seconds?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8

By default, Tomcat logs it's start time in milliseconds.  How can I display this in seconds?

Comment: Divide by 1000?  Do you want Tomcat to report its startup time in seconds, or do you want to take the startup time and determine the number of seconds (not ms) Tomcat took to start?

Comment: I would like Tomcat to report its startup time in seconds.

Comment: Then you will need to modify Tomcat's code.